# When exactly does the value conversion happen in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, java-ee-6

I have consulted several authoritative sources, but either they really contradict each other or I have misunderstood them, or maybe there are more than one conversion taking place? Are there differences between the 1.x and 2.x versions of JSF?

This [IBM post](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/j-jsf2/) states that the conversion happens in the **Apply request values phase** (Phase 2).

This [post by BalusC](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html) says [here](http://balusc.blogspot.de/2006/09/debug-jsf-lifecycle.html#TheFormSubmit) that the default conversion takes place in the **Process Validations Phase** (Phase 3).

The [Oracle JEE6 tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnaqq.html) implies that the conversion takes place in the **Update Model Values Phase** (Phase 4), saying in the description of this phase:

> If the local data cannot be converted to the types specified by the bean properties..

On the other hand, the graphic illustrating the phases in the same tutorial shows conversion errors emerging from both **Process Validations Phase** and **Update Model Values Phase**.

All of the above posts state that if the `immediate` attribute is set to true, all conversions and validations are processed in the **Apply request phase**. This would mean that conversion in that phase is not the default behavior.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [UIInput's documentation](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.1/javadocs/javax/faces/component/UIInput.html) [emphasis mine]:

> During the **Apply Request Values** phase of the request processing lifecycle, the decoded value of this component, usually but not necessarily a String, must be stored - but **not yet converted** - using setSubmittedValue(). If the component wishes to indicate that no particular value was submitted, it can either do nothing, or set the submitted value to null.
>
> By default, during the **Process Validators phase of the request processing lifecycle, the submitted value will be converted to a typesafe object**, and, if validation succeeds, stored as a local value using setValue(). However, if the immediate property is set to true, this processing will occur instead at the end of the Apply Request Values phase.
>
> During the Render Response phase of the request processing lifecycle, conversion for output occurs as for UIOutput.
> There are no differences between JSF 1.x and 2.x versions.

Comment: +1 Thanks, Adam - the docs are the one authoritative source I have not consulted :) I still need some clarification though beyond what's in the UIInput docs - is the IBM post plainly wrong about the conversion in Apply Request Values Phase or is there sth else?  What's about the two arrows in Oracle's graphic? According to the UIInput doc, there is no further conversion in the Update Model Values Phase, so how could there be any conversion errors?

Comment: IBM's article is plain wrong at that point. Oracle's tutorial is good, only the word "converted" is misplaced in the context of the sentence.  Better read it as "casted" or "coerced" (it's EL which does the job here, not JSF `Converter`): *"If the local data cannot be casted to the types specified by the bean properties"*. Note that Oracle's tutorial **do** explicitly mention conversion in the validations phase section.

Comment: @BalusC thank you for clarification. I have also found the part you mention in the Validations Phase: `The JavaServer Faces implementation also completes conversions for input components that do not have the immediate attribute set to true` - have overlooked it the first time

Comment: I'm surprised Big Blue would make such a blunder